# Jenkins Pipeline stage view plugin not showing stage logs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, splunk

Below is the environment I'm currently working on,

Jenkins Version : 2.222.1,

Pipeline: Stage View Plugin  : 2.13,

Splunk-devops plugin version: 1.9.3,

Splunk-devops-extend plugin version: 1.9.3.

Issue 1: Jenkins stage view plug-in supposed to show particular stage logs in pop-up window when clicked 'log', but it is not showing anything.
[image: noStageLogs]

Issue 2: Not sure if it because of above issue, jenkins stage's children information is not sent to Splunk. Earlier we were able to see these information.  For example stages{}.children{}.duration.

Any help would be more appreciated. Thanks.